# Graph Transformation Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I get that because x^2 will be negative the answer will be one of the following a, b, or e. But I don't understand why the answer is a??

[image]

Comment: Did you learn about transformations/translations of functions? When you have a function y = f(x) then the function y= - f(x) will be f(x) reflected in the x-axis. And y = f(x+a) will be shifted left by a units. Edit: (or what Austin says more precisely below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "$+a$" in $-(x + a)^2$ indicates a horizontal shift. Since $a > 0$ (i.e., $a$ is a positive number), this shift must be to the left. Only choice (a) has both the properties of vertical reflection and leftward shift.

Answer (score 0):

$y = -(x + a)^2 = -(x - [-a])^2$

The first minus means that the graph concaves downward. This rules out (c) and (d).

Inserting the middle minus is a way to find the root, which is $[-a]$.

Since $a > 0, -a$ is some negative quantity. This leave (a) as the only choice.